# Disable Full screen in landscape

Tags: android, landscape, landscape-portrait

Is it possible to disable full screen mode in Landscape ?

If not, is any workaround?

Comment: It is supposed to be not a full screen unless you specify so!

Answer (score 2):

Put This code in onCreate() Method.

```
 if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)                 
 {
       //To re-enable full screen:

       getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
       getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);       
}
else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) 
{
       //To disable full screen:

       getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
       getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```